# Push object into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

object is not pushing into array.

```
  groupEventsArray=[]
  groupEvents=(eventOnDate)=>{
    for(i=0;i<eventOnDate.events.length;i++){
      for(j=0;j<eventOnDate.events.length;j++){
        if(eventOnDate.events[i].start==eventOnDate.events[j].start)
        this.groupEventsArray.push(eventsOnDate.events[i])
      }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.groupEventsArray))
  }
```

No error is coming but I think it is stucked in infinite loop.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you share the `eventOnDate` array?

Comment: you have used the variable as `groupEventsArray=[]`, but while pushing, you are using `this.groupEventsArray` instead of `groupEventsArray`

Comment: `but I think it is stucked in infinite loop` not unless `eventOnDate.events.length` is infinite ... but you do realise your code will push every `eventOnDate.events` anyway

Comment: {"fullDate":"2018-10-26T09:30:00.000Z","events":[{"eventId":"43460","title":"Recap of Day 1 and What to Expect day 2","description":"","start":"1540525500","end":"1540525800","location":"Aura 1&2","type":"normal","limit":0,"remaining":-1,"url":"","networking_event":0,"alreadyRegistered":0,"sharing":1,"qa":1,"calendar":1},

Comment: sample: eventOnDetail is like this

Comment: What wrong in using this if I am using is outside function

Comment: You are pushing a value from `eventsOnDate`, but your arrow function's parameter is called `eventOnDate` (without the 's').

Comment: ohh yeah ...it's my mistake btw thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `forEach()` method. The `forEach()` method calls a provided function once for each element in an array, in order.

Note: `forEach()` does not execute the function for array elements without values.

**Syntax**

```
array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

**Example**

```
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
function myFunction(item, index) {
  console.log(item, index);
}

numbers.forEach(myFunction)
```

Looping over an array like this help avoid infinte loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a basic group array by key question. You could do it in the following way:

```js
const data = {
  fullDate: '2018-10-26T09:30:00.000Z',
  events: [
    {
      eventId: '43460',
      start: '1540525500',
    },
    {
      eventId: '43461',
      start: '1540525500',
    },
    {
      eventId: '43462',
      start: '1540525500',
    },
    {
      eventId: '43463',
      start: '1540525510',
    },
  ],
};

const createKey = (t) => t.start;
console.log(
  Object.values(
    data.events
      .map((o) => [o, createKey(o)])
      .reduce((result, [item, key]) => {
        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(item);
        return result;
      }, {}),
  ),
);
```

But the question is probably a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key) (look for answers not using lodash)