# loop multiple arrays and sum the values of same keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiples arrays for different length , Each array has objects of key ,value pairs .

```
[{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2}]
[{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 4},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-28", totalHours: 8}]
[{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 4},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-28", totalHours: 6},{date: "2018-11-30", totalHours: 9}]
```

How to sum the totalHours of same dates considering all arrays?

Comment: Concat all arrays into one and then [group by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516535/1641941) the date key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function as follows:

```
const x = [{ date: '2018-11-26', totalHours: 2 }, { date: '2018-11-27', totalHours: 2 }]

const sum = x.reduce((a, c) => a + c.totalHours, 0)
console.log(sum) // 4
```

Comment: if you would add a third entry, `a` is a number at the second iteration and `a.totalHours` would fail then

Comment: @jonaswilms Yeah, your edit fixes that

Answer (score 0):

You could first create one array with spread syntax and then use `reduce` method to calculate sum.

```js
let a = [{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2}]
let b = [{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 4},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-28", totalHours: 8}]
let c = [{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 4},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-28", totalHours: 6},{date: "2018-11-30", totalHours: 9}]

let sum = [...a, ...b, ...c].reduce((r, {date, totalHours}) => {
  if(!r[date]) r[date] = totalHours;
  else r[date] += totalHours;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [
    ...[{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2}],
    ...[{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 4},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-28", totalHours: 8}],
    ...[{date: "2018-11-26", totalHours: 4},{date: "2018-11-27", totalHours: 2},{date: "2018-11-28", totalHours: 6},{date: "2018-11-30", totalHours: 9}]
];

let result = {};

a.forEach((i) => {
  result[i.date] = result[i.date] || { date: i.date, totalHours: 0 };
  result[i.date].totalHours += i.totalHours;
});

result = Object.values(result)
console.log(result);
```